# Why does applying the call function not pass the correct argument?

Tags: javascript

`Function.prototype` has both `call` and `apply` which can be used to apply a function. Today, I was going to use `apply` for something, but had managed to sneak in a bit of a typo:

```
function foo(a) { console.log('foo', a) }

foo.call.apply(null, [1])
```

It took me a while to realize that I had managed to (presumably while under the influence of something) write `.call` before `.apply`. What surprised me however, is that this will throw a `TypeError`:

```
> function foo(a) { console.log(a) }
undefined
> foo.call.apply(null, [1])
TypeError: object is not a function
    at repl:1:10
```

This had me dumbfounded for a little while, until I figured that it must be because the `call` function gets bound to `null`. So I thought, let's try binding it to `foo` and see what happens:

```
> foo.call.apply(foo, [1])
foo undefined
```

Huh, not quite what I expected. The function is clearly applied, but the argument `a` is for some reason `undefined`. I can't seem to figure this out. Removing the `.call` obviously works as expected:

```
> foo.apply(foo, [1])
foo 1
```

Because I'm now really curious, I tried the opposite: `call` the `apply` function:

```
> foo.apply.call(foo, 1)
foo undefined
```

And this is about as far as I've gotten with this. I have no intention of actually using this for anything – it was an honest mistake in the first place – but I'm very curious to know what's actually going on, and was hoping one of you gurus out there might have an answer.

Why is it that `call` and `apply` behaves this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foo.call.apply(null, [1])
```

This calls `Function.prototype.call` and sets its context to `null` and passes `1` as the argument.

So, it's like you did: `Function.prototype.call(1);` with the context (`this`) set to null.  It's trying to run the `call` function of `null`, so that's why you get "object is not a function".

```
foo.call.apply(foo, [1])
```

This doesn't work because of how the arguments of `call` are set.  You are calling `Function.prototype.call(1);` with the context (`this`) set to `foo`.  It's like you did: `foo.call(1)`.

If you wanted to chain `call` and `apply`, you'd have to do this:

```
foo.call.apply(foo, [null, 1]);
```

Set the context of the `.call` function, then set it's *two* parameters.

Comment: This is a perfect answer, explaining everything clearly and concisely. Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: I wish I could up vote twice, really informative and I feel I've learned something. Love that feeling!

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with a more informative 'foo' function:

```
function log() {
  console.log('args: ', arguments, '\nthis: ', this);
}
```

All functions have the same `call` and `bind` methods. `log.call` is a function, and as a function it has the same `apply` method as every other function. So these two are equivalent:

```
log.apply.call === log.call
log.call === Function.prototype.call
```

Calling this:

```
log.call.apply(null, [1])
```

is the same as calling this:

```
Function.prototype.call.apply(null, [1])
```

The above calls the `Function.prototype.call` method on `window`, passing `1` as the only argument.

This is obviously very wrong; `call` should only be used on functions, not the window object, and the first argument passed to call should be the execution scope, not `1`.